# postgresql - search on json using hibernate specification

Tags: json, postgresql, hibernate, search, specifications

I am facing issue while searching the json field. Any help would be appreciated.. here are the sample code snippet and error what I am facing

Entity class

```java
@TypeDef(name = "cardjsonb", typeClass = JsonBinaryType.class)
public class TransactionEntity {

    @Type(type = "cardjsonb")
    @Column(name = "card_details", columnDefinition = "jsonb")
    private TransactionCardDetails cardDetails;
}


public class TransactionCardDetails {

    private Date expiryDate; //MM-YYYY

    private String cardOnName;

    private String cardNumber;
}
```

specification snippet

```java
 return (root, query, builder) -> builder.equal(
                    builder.function("json_extract_path_text", JsonBinaryType.class, root.get("cardDetails"), builder.literal("cardOnName")),
                    builder.literal("David")
                );
```

Error details

```
ERROR 20628 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: function json_extract_path_text(jsonb, character varying) does not exist
Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
Position: 1732
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jsonb as input, you need to use the `jsonb_extract_path_text` function instead.